# In Akka, how do I manage blocking method calls, like reading from StdIn?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm beginning to using Scala and the AKKA pattern, and i have wrote this code, but it doesn't work and i don't know why...

I have created a little project that read user input from the console.
when this user have wrote a 'keyword', the keyWord Actor (Child) will interpret it and will communicate with the console Actor (Grand parent).

the action Actor will be use to broadcast and do some more stuff.

When i enter the command 'rename' in the console Actor, i enter into the action Actor and after that in the keyWord Actor and enter in the Rename Method, but after that nothing, i didn't enter into the rename method on the console Actor.

Can you help me ?

If you saw any wrong pratice, please don't hesite to tell me how to resolve that :).

Thank you !

Main

```
import ConsoleActor._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("My-Little-IRC")

  val consoleActor = system.actorOf(ConsoleActor.props, "consoleActor")

  consoleActor ! ReadConsoleInput
  system.terminate()
}
```

consoleActor

```
import ActionActor.TreatInputUser
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}

import scala.io.StdIn

object ConsoleActor {

  case class ReadConsoleInput()
  case class StopLoop()
  case class Rename()
  case class WhoIAm()
  def props = Props[ConsoleActor]
}

class ConsoleActor() extends Actor {
  val keyWordActor = context.actorOf(KeyWordActor.props(this.self), "keyWordActor")

  val actionActor = context.actorOf(ActionActor.props(keyWordActor), "actionActor")

  var currentUser: String = ""
  var loop: Boolean = true;

  import ConsoleActor._

  def isValidString( str: String ): Boolean = {
    var isValid: Boolean = false

    if (str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty)
      isValid = true

    isValid
  }

  def initiatePresentation( ) = {
    println("Hi ! Who are you ?")
    currentUser = StdIn.readLine()
    println(s"Nice to meet you ${currentUser}, I'm your console app !")

  }

  def receive = {
    case ReadConsoleInput => {
      initiatePresentation
      var value = ""
      while (loop) {
        println("Yes ?")
        value = StdIn.readLine()
        if (isValidString(value)) {
          actionActor ! TreatInputUser(value)

        }
      }
    }

    case StopLoop => {
      println("stop Loooop !")
      loop = false
    }
    case Rename => {
      println(s"${currentUser} was a good name ! Which is your new name ?")
      currentUser = StdIn.readLine()
      println(s"Nice to meet you -again- ${currentUser}")
    }
    case WhoIAm =>{
      println(s"I'm ${currentUser}")
    }
  }
}
```

actionActor

```
import ActionActor.TreatInputUser

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask

import scala.concurrent.Await


object ActionActor {
  case class TreatInputUser(string: String)
  def props(keyWordActor: ActorRef)  = Props(new ActionActor(keyWordActor))
}

class ActionActor(keyWordActor:  ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import KeyWordActor._

  def receive = {
    case TreatInputUser(string) => {
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
      var isKeyWord = keyWordActor ? IsKeyWord(string)
      val isKeyWordResult = Await.result(isKeyWord, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[ Boolean ]
      println(isKeyWordResult)
      if (isKeyWordResult) {
       keyWordActor ! HandleKeyWord(string)
      }
      else {
       println("bla bla bla")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

keyWord actor

```
import ConsoleActor.{Rename, StopLoop, WhoIAm}
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}

object KeyWordActor {
  case class IsKeyWord(key : String)
  case class HandleKeyWord(key : String)

  def props(consoleActor: ActorRef) = Props(new KeyWordActor(consoleActor))
}


class KeyWordActor(consoleActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  import KeyWordActor._

  val KeysWord : Map[ String, ()=> Any] = Map("rename" -> renameFunction, "stop" -> stopFunction, "42" -> uselessfunction, "john doe ?" -> AmIJohnDoe)

  def renameFunction() = {
    println("here")
    consoleActor ! Rename
  }

  def stopFunction() = {
    consoleActor ! StopLoop
  }

  def uselessfunction() = {
    println("useless")
  }

  def AmIJohnDoe() ={
    consoleActor ! WhoIAm
  }

  def receive = {
    case IsKeyWord(key) => {
      sender ! KeysWord.contains(key.toLowerCase)
    }
    case HandleKeyWord(key) => {
      if (KeysWord.contains(key.toLowerCase)) {
        KeysWord(key.toLowerCase)()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In `ConsoleActor`, you're blocking in your `receive` method. [Blocking requires careful management](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management). Rather, read from `StdIn` in `Main`, and send a message to `ConsoleActor` (or someone appropriate) when a line is read.

Comment: Hey @LászlóvandenHoek, when you said that i should read user input into the ´Main', do you means that the 'While' loop must be in the 'Main'? if yes, how the 'keyWord' actor will be able to stop the loop ?

Comment: My previous comment stands, but now that I have fully understood your question, I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You must not block in the `receive` method. The way you wrote it (with a `while` loop), the initial `ReadConsoleInput` message never finishes processing, and any subsequent messages (like `StopLoop`) will sit untouched in the Actor mailbox forever.

If you must selectively read from `StdIn` (as opposed to just continuously reading in e.g. your `Main` class) then one approach could be to change your `ConsoleActor` so that when it receives a `ReadConsoleInput` message, it should just try to do `StdIn.readLine` *once*, and forward the result to the `ActionActor`. Since the `StdIn.readLine` call itself is also blocking, you should do it asynchronously. The "[pipe](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/futures.html#use-with-actors)" pattern comes in handy here:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
import scala.concurrent.Future

//...

def receive = {
  case ReadConsoleInput =>
    import context.dispatcher //provide a thread pool to do async work
    Future(StdIn.readLine())  //read a line of input asynchronously
      .filter(isValidString)  //only continue if line is valid
      .map(TreatInputUser)    //wrap the (valid) String in a message
      .pipeTo(actionActor)    //forward it
  case Rename => ...
}
```

This way, the `ConsoleActor` immediately becomes available again to process new messages, while your `ActionActor` will receive a `TreatInputUser` message whenever the user finishes typing a line in the console.

You can apply the same pattern inside your `ActionActor`, instead of relying on `Await`.

If you want to close the loop so you can continue sending messages, I'd use [behaviour](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome) to ensure that two `StdIn.readLine` calls are not interfering.

Comment: Now i can reach the 'console Actor' though the 'keyWord Actor' Thanks ! but now, i can only wrote one command, i have lost the possibility to wrote more than one.
What i should change to be able to write more than one command ?